# Parse microseconds in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to convert the following CSV content, which contains a timestamp in microseconds, via the **CSVRecordReader** to an AvroRecord via the **AvroRecordSetWriter**:

```
timestamp,value    
1551784149996000,1
```

I'm using the following Avro schema:

```
{
  "name": "TestRecord",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type" :
      {
        "type" : "long",
        "logicalType" : "timestamp-micros"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "value",
      "type": "long"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the **CSVRecordReader** seems to interpret the microseconds as milliseconds and therefore the output of the AvorRecordSetWriter contains three more zeros:

```
1551784750036000000
```

> Timestamp fields will be assumed to be number of milliseconds since
>   epoch (Midnight, Jan 1, 1970 GMT)
>   https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.csv.CSVReader/index.html

How can I parse microseconds in NiFi and convert it to Avro or Parquet using this schema?

Maybe the following Instant ISO format is somehow supported by any NiFi RecordReader?

```
2019-03-01T13:12:34.567123Z
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent `* 1000` in [`getLongFromTimestamp`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-extension-utils/nifi-record-utils/nifi-avro-record-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/avro/AvroTypeUtil.java#L686)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use an `UpdateRecord` processor following the `ConvertRecord` (if you need to retain microsecond precision) or preceding the `ConvertRecord` (if you only need millisecond precision) to trim the last three digits from that field.

You can use the Record Path function [`substringBeforeLast`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#substringbeforelast) to trim via `substringBeforeLast(timestamp, '000')`.

Comment: The `AvroRecordSetWriter` in my `ConvertRecord` seems to add these zero values at the end during a milli to micro seconds conversion. If I use a `UpdateRecord` afterwards to truncate the zeros as suggested I get the following error:
---
`IllegalTypeConversionException: Could not convert value [1550865604871] of type java.lang.String to Timestamp for field timestamp because the value is not in the expected date format: org.apache.nifi.avro.AvroTypeUtil$$Lambda$1007/1287416711@3eba4c98`